# require() is giving me an error because Firefox is skipping directories

Tags: php, firefox, fatal-error

This code works in every browser except Firefox and I can't seem to find out why. I have tried to require all the way back to the root dir, but it still throws me the error:

> "Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear')"

```
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
```

Comment: The browser shouldn't have any influence over this.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but it works in every browser except Firefox and I can't figure out why.

Comment: For sure it has nothing to do with the browser. The browser can not, in any way, influence something that is run on the server.

Comment: Try clearing the caches of all your browsers and see if the behavior becomes consistent after that.

Comment: WAT. The browser doesn't even KNOW what directories php is rooting around in... how could it skip them? ;) Sounds like cache issue as @Don'tPanic mentioned. Its just pulling the broken state of a page out of its rear for you to see, instead of actually hitting the server for new data.

Comment: @IncredibleHat actually, I was thinking the opposite. The browsers that are working are serving a version of the page cached before the error was introduced. Just guessing, of course. :)

Comment: @Don'tPanic haha! Yeah.... hmm. Thats a curious thought. Although I use Chrome so much, I've never seen it behave like that. However he didnt mention Chrome, so, yeah, huh...

Comment: Alright, so I cleared the caches in every browser(Chrome, Firefox, etc..) but they all still work except for Firefox.

Comment: Fixed it! I accidentally had a copy of the file in the directory above the one where it was supposed to be. Thank you everyone for giving me some debugging help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser has no influence over how paths work on your server.

Most simply, you do not have the correct path in your require statement.

However, I would recommend using composer and its autoload script to bring PHPMailer into your project.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox should NOT be able to influence any of this.

### Checking whether none of your browsers cache old/new version

Try:

- clearing history and cache and reloading (hard reload <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>)
- opening it in a Private window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) (names and shortcuts vary across browsers)
- checking the URL (you may have loaded an old URL from history) and making sure you have the right one
- checking the protocol (http vs https) and making sure you have the right one

If any of these steps help, it definitely isn't Firefox' issue.

Is it a simple page you open, or do you rely on GET or POST variables? Is there any chance other browsers have cached an older, working version, and only Firefox shows the current broken results? Try renaming the file to something you haven't had there before and re-opening it, or the steps I listed on other browsers.

### Checking whether you are editing the right file

When I get weird behavior like this, I usually try editing the file to show something different (like `echo "current file <br>";` at the beginning of the PHP file) first to see for sure I am opening the right file from everywhere and the changes to code take effect. I've had lots of such problems and it usually were switching underscore and dash, opening from production server instead of development one, etc. It's a nightmare when your debugging can't seem to work whatever you do and in the end you find out you didn't do anything at all (to the file you were opening).

### Including absolute path

This won't help with the "Why only Firefox" question, but you might want to use absolute path to be safe when including, or relative to your current folder.

Instead of

```
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
```

try

```
require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
```

or

```
require __DIR__ . '/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
// __DIR__ is a Magic constant showing directory of currently running script (if included, then path of included one)
// see http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php
```

or

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
// DOCUMENT_ROOT is the root directory of your web, like /var/www/html/site.com
```

so the parser doesn't look for the file in your include path (unless that is where your PHPMailer is located).

Also, I'd use `require_once` rather than `require` when loading libraries.

Comment: Fixed it! I had a copy of the file in the dir above where it was supposed to be!

Comment: Glad you found it! I may have gone a bit overboard with the suggestions, hope it was of some use :)

Comment: It was great help! Why would you use require_once instead of require?

Comment: In case you for some reason run the code twice, it has the libraries already loaded so won't load them again, re-initializing everything, so you save some computational time. Not a big issue on a small site, but when your audience widens and/or your code grows more complex, it may prevent some server overloading. Require says "load the library now", require_once says "load the library if not yet loaded".

Comment: Loading twice is needed e.g. for a config file you want to get re-read after you changed something, or content re-included for another location in the output. But if you need to send two mails during the code execution and include this whole script twice, or have the same include in more places in your code, there's no need to re-initialize the whole PHPMailer. Of course, as long as you include the library only once during each execution, it won't make any difference. 
Also, if I helped, I'd appreciate an upvote - I'm trying to get the commenting privilege :)

Comment: That is simple enough! Thank you very much! And I did upvote you, I just haven't been on the site very long as a member so my upvotes don't quite count yet I guess... o.O

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about this aspect of this site :D Anyways, glad to have helped you.